# Websphere jdbc connection unavalible

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, java-7, enterprise

I have servlet that return data in json. I try to execute few querys in loop. If array of querys contain less then 5 querys it work well. But if i try to execute 10 querys in loop it stacked and return NullPointerExceprion.
here my code

```
private JSONArray getQueryResultJSONById(String queryId, String formName, JSONObject paramsJSON) {
String sql = getQuery(queryId, formName);
if (sql != null) {
    try {
        Connector connector = new Connector(Defaults.DS_DEFAULT);
        connector.prepareStatement(sql);
        connector.setPreparedJSONParams(paramsJSON);
        connector.executePrepared();
        JSONArray dbrs = ResultSetConverter.convertToJSON(connector.getPreparedSelect());
        connector.close();
        return dbrs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Connector class:

```
public void prepareStatement(String query) {
    try {
        this.sql = query;
        if (connection.isClosed()) {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logException(e);
    }
}
public void setPreparedJSONParams(JSONObject paramsJSON) {
    if (paramsJSON != null) {
        JSONArray array = paramsJSON.getJSONArray("params");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            String paramValue = array.getString(i);
            if (NULL.equals(paramValue)) {
                setPreparedParam(i + 1, (String) null);
            } else {
                setPreparedParam(i + 1, array.getString(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
public boolean executePrepared() {
    try {
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logException(e);
        return false;
    }
}
public ResultSet getPreparedSelect() {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logException(e);
    }
    return resultSet;
}
public void close() {
    try {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logException(e);
    }
}
```

in loop i try do like this to execute querys:

```
queryRs = new JSONArray(uiQueryService.getQueryResultById(querys.get(i), "REPORT", params.toString()));
```

I tried to debug this place to see what request produce the problem, but in debugger each of request work well and result successfully returns. I have no any idea how to resolve the problem

exception :

```
J2CA0045E: Во время вызова метода createOrWaitForConnection для ресурса jdbc/Oep/NonXaDataSourceWeb соединение недоступно.
[18.03.19 13:08:33:025 MSK] 0000f40e TaskUtils$Log E org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler handleError Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
                                 org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009
                at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:243)
                at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.pollDiagnosisLock(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
                at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
                at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
                at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:483)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:190)
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009
                at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1680)
                at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:661)
                at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:611)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.getConnection(Unknown Source)
                at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:205)
                ... 20 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: CWTE_NORMAL_J2CA1009
                at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1783)
                at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3874)
                at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3094)
                at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
                at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
                at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:644)
                ... 28 more
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace and mark the line in which the NPE happens in the code above.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you create a new `JSONArray` when the method you call returns a `JSONArray`?

Comment: Show us the code for `connector.close()`.

Comment: @AaronDigulla oh sorry, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218758/websphere-jdbc-connection-unavalible/55219712#55219712) by [Aaron Digulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34088/aaron-digulla) there is one more thing to configure if you want to connect more JDBC connections concurrently. You can set ***Maximum connections*** property for your datasource on Websphere application server:

> Resources > JDBC > Data Sources > data_source > [Additional Properties] Connection pool properties

This set maximum number of JDBC connections in pool. Please see more here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/udat_conpoolset.html

But still you have to have good management of connection releasing to avoid usage of all connections (so avoid blocking resources by not used connections).

Answer (score 2):

This feels like you're running out of connections.

There are two bugs in `connection.close()`: You need to close the prepared statement, the statement and then the connection (reverse order in which you created these resources).

Maybe one of these throws an exception and then the connection is never closed. So look for more errors in your log and use this code:

```
if (x != null) {
    try { x.close(); } catch(Exception e) { log.warn("Failed to close X", e); }
}
```

i.e. handle exception per call to `close()` so the other resources get closed as well.

If that doesn't fix it, look at how the `Connector` is used and designed. Usually, an app can only create a few (around 10) connections to the database at the same time. Therefore, apps use a connection pool which handles creating and closing connections. When you ask for a new connection, you'll get a proxy for one in the pool. That means every real JDBC connection is used for many SQL statements and queries before it's closed.

That way, an app can't starve a database by opening thousands of expensive connections and still use a simple "open/close connection" design.

Comment: So in my case, the developer who was develop Connector class has some mistakes that generate new connection for each new instacle was called. i fix it, and problem disappear